# Length of slice in Highcharts pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

Is there a way to change the length of a selected slice in highcharts.js?  I'm not looking to offset from the center - but I would like the selected slice to extend farther than the others.  I couldn't seem to find a place in the API to affect the length of a slice.

Comment: Try to use my solution from [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874440/change-mouseover-point-in-highcharts/18875020#18875020).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using 'slicedOffset', here is the fiddle from the API

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            slicedOffset: 20
        }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-slicedoffset-20/

Comment: I may have misread your question, I think you're saying that this is actually what you don't want to do. Sorry about that.

Comment: The only other thing I can think is the 'sliced' property of series data http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/sliced/
this allows one special slice to appear unique, not just when it is clicked