# Change mouseover point in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, svg, highcharts

Can somebody help me with my problem.

I have this piecharts,

[image]

and i need to change point( segment ), when i mouseover on it

[image]

What the best way you can advise me?

Maybe something like this, change point, but i don't know how to do this

```
plotOptions: {
        series:{
            point:{
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function( e ){
                        console.log( this )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to update only graphic using `element.attr()`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/rh5fz92q/

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(e){
                        this.defaultR = this.graphic.r;
                        this.graphic.attr({
                            r: 200
                        });
                    },
                    mouseOut: function(e){
                        this.graphic.attr({
                            r: this.defaultR
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately the fiddle isn't available anymore.